# CentOS 5 - Install PHP intl

Tags: php, whm, centos5, intl

Server:

- CENTOS 5.11 i686
- WHM 54.0

I've tried several approaches installing `intl` PHP extension.

---

First approach is straight forward.
In WHM i enter PHP PECL, and when trying to install `intl`:

```
 downloading intl-3.0.0.tgz ...
 Starting to download intl-3.0.0.tgz (248,200 bytes)
....................................................done: 248,200 bytes
 150 source files, building
 running: phpize
 Configuring for:
 PHP Api Version:         20121113
 Zend Module Api No:      20121212
 Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
 Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] : building in /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootnuhZM5/intl-3.0.0
 running: /root/tmp/pear/intl/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=DEFAULT
 checking for egrep... grep -E
 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
 checking for cc... cc
 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
 checking for suffix of executables...
 checking for suffix of object files... o
 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
 checking for cc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
 checking for icc... no
 checking for suncc... no
 checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
 checking for system library directory... lib
 checking if compiler supports -R... no
 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
 checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
 checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
 checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
 checking if debug is enabled... no
 checking if zts is enabled... no
 checking for re2c... re2c
 checking for re2c version... invalid
 configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
 checking for gawk... gawk
 checking whether to enable internationalization support... yes, shared
 checking for icu-config... /usr/bin/icu-config
 checking for location of ICU headers and libraries... /usr
 checking for ICU 4.0 or greater... found 3.6
 configure: error: ICU version 4.0 or later is required
 ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/intl/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=DEFAULT' failed
 The intl.so object is not in /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
 Tidying /usr/local/lib/php.ini...
 No changes
 Tidying /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/54/etc/php.ini...
 No changes
```

Tried finding that `intl.so object` manually online, no luck.
I'm afraid I might get non-compatible version and screw things up. Nonetheless, this would be a bad solution.

---

Second approach is running pecl library via `ssh`:

```
root@ns1 [/]# /usr/bin/pecl install intl
```

and the response:

```
downloading intl-3.0.0.tgz ...
Starting to download intl-3.0.0.tgz (248,200 bytes)
....................................................done: 248,200 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/root/tmp/pear/cache/intl-3.0.0.tgz"
Download of "pecl/intl" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/intl"
Download failed
install failed
```

---

Researching online, I tried to update `icu` via `yum`.
It finds `php53-intl.i386` package and says it's already installed.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Installed Packages
php53-intl.i386
```

PHP was excluded in the config, and I had to remove it from the list. I wonder why, in addition when I `yum list php`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Available Packages
php.i386                   5.1.6-45.el5_11                                                                                                                    updates
```

And `php -v` says `PHP 5.5.31 (cli) (built: Jan 14 2016 18:46:05)`
This also might be useful, `rpm -qa | grep php` response:

```
cpanel-php54-Horde-Auth-2.1.8-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Compress-2.1.2-5.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Argv-2.0.11-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Secret-2.0.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Service-Twitter-2.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-SOAP-0.13.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Denmark-0.1.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-CssMinify-1.0.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Cache-1.5.6-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-HTML-Template-IT-1.3.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Prefs-2.7.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Itip-2.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Serialize-2.0.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Css-Parser-1.0.6-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Support-2.1.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Constraint-2.0.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Service-Facebook-2.0.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Brazil-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Venezuela-0.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-HTTP-1.4.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Text-Figlet-1.0.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Smtp-1.9.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-ListHeaders-1.2.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Injector-2.0.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Image-2.3.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-XML-Parser-1.3.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Kolab-Format-2.0.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Spain-0.1.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Iceland-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Console-Table-1.1.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-MDB2-2.4.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-trean-1.1.1-5.cp1152
cpanel-php54-zendopt-6.0.0-1.cp1142
cpanel-php54-Horde-Translation-2.2.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Stream-Filter-2.0.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Routes-2.0.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Oauth-2.0.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Mail-1.2.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Ireland-0.1.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Croatia-0.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Mail-2.6.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-nag-4.2.4-7.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Browser-2.0.9-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Cache-2.5.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-View-2.0.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Log-2.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Feed-2.0.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Finland-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-USA-0.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Pack-1.0.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Core-2.20.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Crypt-2.5.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Socket-Client-2.0.0-5.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Autoloader-2.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Xml-Element-2.0.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Perms-2.1.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Queue-1.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Kolab-Session-2.0.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Japan-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Italy-0.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Idna-1.0.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-PEAR-Command-Packaging-0.3.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Dav-1.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Yaml-2.0.2-4.cp1152
php53-common-5.3.3-26.el5_11
cpanel-php54-Horde-Exception-2.0.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Net-Socket-1.0.14-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-SpellChecker-2.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Cli-2.0.6-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Net-URL-1.0.15-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Net-DNS2-1.4.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Serbia-0.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Germany-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Console-Color-1.0.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Icalendar-2.0.11-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-turba-4.2.6-6.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Imap-Client-2.28.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Group-2.0.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Vfs-2.2.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Text-Flowed-2.0.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Xml-Wbxml-2.0.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-History-2.3.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-SessionHandler-2.2.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-horde-lz4-1.0.8-2.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Pdf-2.0.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Services-Weather-1.4.7-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Romania-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Slovenia-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-PHPdotNet-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-JavascriptMinify-1.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Net-FTP-1.3.7-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-XML-SVG-1.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-horde-5.2.5-13.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Timezone-1.0.9-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-webmail-5.2.6-6.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Token-2.0.6-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-1.4.7-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Share-2.0.7-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-HashTable-1.2.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Australia-0.2.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-SanMarino-0.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Log-1.12.7-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-File-Fstab-2.0.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Rpc-2.1.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Mail-Autoconfig-1.0.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-5.4.31-4.cp1150
cpanel-php54-Horde-Role-1.0.1-5.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Notification-2.0.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Lock-2.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-XML-Serializer-0.20.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Imsp-2.0.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Norway-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-UNO-0.1.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-ingo-3.2.5-6.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Text-Filter-2.3.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Compress-Fast-1.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Stream-Wrapper-2.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Template-2.0.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-ElasticSearch-1.0.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Netherlands-0.1.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Turkey-0.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Auth-SASL-1.0.6-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Mime-Viewer-2.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-kronolith-4.2.7-7.cp1152
php53-intl-5.3.3-26.el5_11
cpanel-php54-Horde-Nls-2.0.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Alarm-2.2.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Http-2.1.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Controller-2.0.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Net-IMAP-1.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Portugal-0.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Sweden-0.1.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Net-Sieve-1.3.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-File-Find-1.3.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Form-2.0.9-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-imp-6.2.8-6.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Util-2.5.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-LoginTasks-2.0.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Editor-2.0.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Date-Parser-2.0.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-0.21.8-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Mail-Mime-1.8.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Austria-0.1.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Russia-0.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-DB-1.7.14-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Net-UserAgent-Detect-2.5.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Mime-2.9.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-mnemo-4.2.6-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-ioncube-4.5.2-1.cp1142
cpanel-php54-Horde-Url-2.2.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Stream-1.6.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Text-Diff-2.1.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Crypt-Blowfish-1.0.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-HTTP-Request-1.4.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Czech-0.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-HTTP-WebDAV-Server-1.0.0RC8-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-XML-RPC-1.5.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Data-2.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-timeobjects-2.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-sourceguardian-8.3-1.cp1142
cpanel-php54-Horde-Date-2.1.0-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Tree-2.0.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Db-2.2.3-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-Rdo-2.0.4-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Net-SMTP-1.6.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-EnglandWales-0.1.5-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Date-Holidays-Ukraine-0.1.2-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-File-1.4.1-4.cp1152
cpanel-php54-content-2.0.4-5.cp1152
cpanel-php54-Horde-SyncMl-2.0.3-4.cp1152
```

---

I am lost here.

Comment: either you've built php 5.5 yourself, or it was installed using different repo(which is not enabled now), what's in your yum.repos.d?

Comment: also, do 'rpm -qa | grep php' to find out what's installed

Comment: Also, this question is probably more suitable for serverfault rather than stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Michail i build PHP via WHM's 'easy apache'. Edited the question to include rpm php related packages.

Comment: what about 'which php'?

Comment: you can try to build updated icu by using this tutorial: http://davidalger.com/sysops/upgrading-icu-to-install-orocrm-on-centos-5/ and then trying to install php-intl using WHM

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using EasyApache, you can install the Intl extension within EasyApache (not through the WHM PHP Extension install area), which I would recommend. EasyApache is very sensitive to outside modifications/changes due to the nature of the script :)

WHM 54.0 build 12
Easy Apache v3.32.10

- Go to EasyApache3 in WHM
- Under "cPanel Recommended Profiles" next to "Basic Apache 2.4" click on the gear icon to customize this profile
- Step 1: Keep Apache 2.4 (unless you absolutely need Apache 2.2)
- Step 2: Select your PHP version, I recommend php 5.5 or 5.6 depending on application requirements
- Step 3: Usually the default settings here are sufficient, but the next click the **"Exhaustive Options List"** button
- Step 4: You can skip the "Apache" modules section, the "PHP Modules" section is about 50% down the page. Select any PHP modules you need (including Intl) add-on together. You can also leave the rest default as well.
- **Click "Save & Build"**

If you run into any errors during the build process I highly recommend you contact cPanel support or your server provider if you have technical assistance. Most all of the plugins you need for PHP are installable via EasyApache and it is the safest way to install them.

If you tried this already, use a fresh "cPanel Recommended Profile" and be sure to only check the minimum required options, as some addons might not be compatible with others in some cases.

Starting fresh generally works for me when I am having issues with EasyApache.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. Using EasyApache is the best way of building PHP in WHM for cPanel